# How to exclude generated sourceSet from jacoco plugin in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco, source-sets

I have searched a lot and all the questions and answers were about excluding a specific package structure.

I have a project with `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` and `src/generated/java` directories.

Contents of `main` and `generated` are compiled into same directory.

Is there any way to exclude files in `src/generated/java/` files from jacoco plugin source set?

Comment: Do `generated` files have a common package name ?

Comment: Nope. they are generated by QueryDSL, so each class has a class with just a Q in front of its name and in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: '**/Q*')
        })
    }
}
```

If it's not enough (some classes from `src/main/java` begin with `Q`), maybe try to override the `querydsl.prefix` property which default value is `Q`, with something more unique.

Comment: If you look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html#org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport:sourceDirectories there is a sourceDirectories property in JacocoReport class. But I don't know how to configure it in Gradle build file.